# adding drivers using python

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I want to add a driver to multiple objects within a collection using an empty as target object. This is how far I came [image: Screenshot]. I am facing two problems: 1. the script only adds a driver to the active object, not to ALL of the objects. 2. The Python [image: ToolTips] tell me that linking the empty as target object should be something with DriverTarget.id but I cannot figure out where to put this within my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy

empty = bpy.data.objects["Empty"]

for obj in bpy.data.collections["Collection"].all_objects:
    if obj.type == "MESH":
        fcs = obj.driver_add("delta_location", -1)
        for i, fc in enumerate(fcs):
            dr = fc.driver
            v = fc.driver.variables.new()
            tar0 = v.targets[0]
            tar0.id = empty
            tar0.data_path = f"location[{i}]"
            dr.expression = v.name
```