# How to add a driver to a camera via python?

Tags: python, drivers

I have two groups of cameras.

```
cam_group={
'fbCamera': 'C_0F0'
'fbCamera.001': 'C_0F1'
'fbCamera.002': 'C_0F2'
'fbCamera.003': 'C_0F3'
'fbCamera.004': 'C_0F4'
'fbCamera.005': 'C_0F5'
'fbCamera.006': 'C_0F6'
'fbCamera.007': 'C_0F7'
'fbCamera.008': 'C_0F8'
'fbCamera.009': 'C_0F9'
}
```

I want to add a driver for the camera focus for the group behind so that

```
bpy.data.cameras["C_0F0"].lens=bpy.data.cameras["fbCamera"].lens，
bpy.data.cameras["C_0F1"].lens=bpy.data.cameras["fbCamera.001"].lens
bpy.data.cameras["C_0F2"].lens=bpy.data.cameras["fbCamera.002"].lens
```

as shown in the picture, how can I write the code in python?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took inspiration from [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/274621/53447).

If you right-click the input camera's lens property, copy as driver, then paste as driver on the target camera, you get a functional driver.

The goal is basically to reproduce that:

[image]

Loop through the list of cameras, make the driver, set its scripted expression to the name of your future var, add a variable input, set its input type to cameras, set the target camera, and finally the property data path.

```py
import bpy

cam_group = {
    'fbCamera': 'C_0F0',
    'fbCamera.001': 'C_0F1'
}

for camera_name, target_camera_name in cam_group.items():
    fcurve = bpy.data.cameras[target_camera_name].driver_add("lens")
    driver = fcurve.driver
    driver.expression = "varLens"
    
    var_input = driver.variables.new()
    var_input.type = 'SINGLE_PROP'
    var_input.name = "varLens"
    
    target = var_input.targets[0]
    target.id_type = 'CAMERA'
    target.id = bpy.data.cameras[camera_name]
    target.data_path = "lens"
```